# forEach loop to insert name in div inside li tag

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var elements = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
demoP = document.getElementById("demo");

elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
  demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + "index[" + index + "]: " + item + "<br>";
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="border: 5px solid black;" id="div_demo">
      <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hi,

I'm new to JavaScript. I want to display array names in separate **div tag inside li**. So far I have managed to get array list to display one below another in single div & li. I want to display each name in separate **div inside li**.

Comment: try creating new `div` element each time in your loop and then insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add every li in a div and append it to the document in every iteration.

```js
  

var elements = ['rock', 'paper','scissor'];
  
  demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
  elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
  
  newlistitem = document.createElement("li"); 
  newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.setAttribute("style", "border: 5px solid black;");
  newdiv.setAttribute("id", "div_demo");
 
  newdiv.innerHTML = "index[" + index + "]: " + item + "<br>";
  
  demoP.appendChild(newlistitem);
  newlistitem.appendChild(newdiv);

});
```

```html
<ul> 
  <p id="demo"></p>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<ul id="navp">
    </ul>

var mainList = document.getElementById("navp");
```

Loop the list with your array

```
elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
        var elem = document.createElement("li");
        elem.innerHTML = "<div>"+item+"</div>";
        mainList.appendChild(elem);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have already have the answer, just change your markup when adding the div

note: i have styled the div to make it more visible

```js
var elements = ['rock', 'paper','scissor'];
 demoP = document.getElementById("demo");
 
 elements.forEach(function(item, index) {
  demoP.innerHTML = demoP.innerHTML + "<div>index[" + index + "]: " + item + "</div>";
 });
```

```css
#demo div{
   border: 1px solid #f00;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <div style="border: 5px solid black;" id="div_demo">
   <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```