# How to create an element inside a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, clock

NOTE: Please look at the code structure. You can't append node to array, same as you can't .pop or .remove an item from node.

I'm trying to create an element inside the for loop, or forEach(tried both).

I'm getting the values, however they are in an array.

So they are nested inside the ul, but they don't have the li tag.

I tried to add the li tag, but I can't make it happen.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/opaxqx?editors=1010

Here is the code:

```
    // Get te location
// Make the : blink

//var location = document.querySelector('.clock-location');

function abbrev(a,b) {
  return a.substr(0,b);
}

function currentDay() {
  // Go to array
  // If today day (number) matched one of the array
  // To this add active
}

function displayTime() {

  var clockTime = document.querySelector('.clock-time');
  var clockDay = document.querySelector('.clock-day');
  var clockWeekdays = document.querySelector('.clock-weekdays');

  var date = new Date();

  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Monday";
  weekday[1] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[2] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[3] = "Thursday";
  weekday[4] = "Friday";
  weekday[5] = "Saturday";
  weekday[6] =  "Sunday";

  var singleDay = [];

  // weekday.forEach(function(day){
  //  singleDay.push(abbrev(day,3));
  // });

  for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
    var day = weekday[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li').innerHTML = day;
    singleDay.push(abbrev(li,3));
  }

  // Mechanics
  var todayDay = weekday[date.getDay()];

  // Display
  clockDay.innerHTML = abbrev(todayDay,3);
  clockWeekdays.innerHTML = singleDay;

  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}



displayTime();

// Get the time

//Loop Throw weekdays - show 3 letters
```

Comment: what is this line supposed to do? `var li = document.createElement('li').innerHTML = day;` What do YOU think this line means/does?

Comment: I was testing many stuff. This here creates element li and inside puts the day, which is weekday[i] so it should loop all of that inside the li lol something like that. 

It didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forEach loop to insert name in div inside li tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161924/foreach-loop-to-insert-name-in-div-inside-li-tag)

Comment: Possible duplicate, but the question is different. Especially with the code structure :) But whatever, let it be for loop, which is different than for each :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your loop a little (removed `push` step and new child will be appended on every loop iteration):

```
for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
  var day = weekday[i];
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = abbrev(day,3);
  clockWeekdays.appendChild(li);
}
```

And don't forget to comment/remove this line:

```
clockWeekdays.innerHTML = singleDay;
```

otherwise your `innerHTML` will be overridden. And here is the working codepen:

https://codepen.io/commercialsuicide/pen/WdaojM?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, get rid of the last line where you push the li into an array and instead use appendChild() to add the newly created li element to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: AppendChild works only on node elements. While this is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the element properly, and then use `appendChild`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
    var day = weekday[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = abbrev(day,3);
    clockWeekdays.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: AppendChild works only on node elements, while this is an array. So it won't work, and in fact, It didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought you were helping me :D My code is connected to array to make it work :D But that code didn't work either, and it doesn't work with the structure of my code.

Comment: Or am I wrong? Unless you're appending that to clockWeekdays which makes sense, then we don't need an array. So that would loop, yeah, I guess that's another way to do it.